# Configuration File for Features

Tags: 2010, configuration, xml

I am creating some features in SharePoint 2010. I need to have some settings for all the features that I intend to keep in a xml file that should get deployed to 14 hive. On feature activation, settings should be read from the xml file. How can  I have a common xml file for all my features and how to read it back from 14 hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454269.aspx) element in the feature schema. It allows you to store config information in the form of key value pair. Here is a [article](http://www.devexpertise.com/2009/02/03/adding-custom-properties-to-sharepoint-features/) that describes it usage.
Also you can always use resource file (see [here](http://sharepointcore.blogspot.com/2011/12/sharepoint-read-resource-file.html)), but I guess properties element of feature schema would be better way to do it.

Comment: Well then again it would need re compiling and re deployment if I need to change the values.

Answer (score 3):

Sharepoint includes a hierarchical configuration manager that can safely store and retrieve configuration settings. You can use [sharepoint property bags](http://msmvps.com/blogs/officept/archive/2011/12/22/introduction-to-property-bags-in-sharepoint.aspx) to store/retrieve config settings.

SharePoint 2010 does not provide a user interface to read and write these configuration settings at run time. To do this, you can use the property bag editor on CodePlex: [codeplex](http://pbs2010.codeplex.com/)

Comment: + 1. Sorry I didn't read your reply before posting mine. But I have added some comments

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you to use Property key in Feature.xml because every time you change values for Property key, you will have to re-deploy the Feature.

I would recommend you using the property bags at SPWeb/SPSite/SPWebApplication Level

Comment: Some example: http://www.fivenumber.com/understanding-sharepoint-property-bag-settings/